# Maven project imported to eclipse from git is missing "Maven Dependencies" library

Tags: eclipse, maven, m2eclipse, m2e

Using latest Oxygen.

I started working on a new Maven project that was initialized from a template.  I cloned the git repo in Eclipse and built it successfully from the command line (outside of eclipse).

I then right-clicked on the repo and selected "Import Projects" and let it import the one project.  When it finished, it definitely knew it was a Java project, and a Maven project. The "M" and "J" are in the icon.  It set my existing src/main/java and src/test/java trees as source directories.  The project context menu has a "Maven" menu with expected menu items.

However, even after Eclipse finished building, there were many errors in the project.  I noticed that in the Package Explorer, the lines in the project that represent "library" entries had the "JRE System Library" and "Referenced Libraries", but it didn't have the "Maven Dependencies" entry that I see in other Maven projects that don't have this problem.

Confirming this, in the "Java Build Path" section of the project properties, the "Libraries" tab just has the "JRE System Library", but not the "Maven Dependencies" entry.

Looking in the .classpath file, I don't see any mention of Maven at all.  In working Maven projects, I see the "maven.pomderived" property throughout that file.

Also note that when I saw these symptoms after the first import, I then deleted the project and then reimported it a different way, from the main "Import" menu and selecting "Existing Maven Projects".  The result was the same.

What can I do here?

**Update**:

I tried deleting the project, not the contents, and then manually deleting the .classpath, .project, and .settings, then reimporting as "Existing Maven Projects".

The result is a Maven project, not a Java project.  The icon has the "M", not the "J", and it doesn't have a Java builder.

I tried doing "Update Project".  No change.

I've imported many Maven projects, even in this same Eclipse instance and workspace, using the same strategy, and I've never seen this problem.

**Update**:

Technically, I've solved the problem, but not in the way I really wanted.

I simply compared the .project and .classpath files with a working Maven project, and I hand-edited the files to reflect what the working project was doing.  It's now all working fine.  I hope I don't have to do this again.

Comment: Do not use mvn eclipse:eclipse anymore long being deprecated use M2E of Eclipse instead.

Comment: Just so it's clear, if you're directing that comment at me instead of the original commenter (who has now apparently deleted his comment), I'm using Maven in Eclipse, which means I'm using M2E by default.

Comment: Are you using plugins that are not emulated by m2e (you're told when importing)

Comment: No, I saw no significant messages from starting the import to its completion.

Comment: The problem sometimes happened to me a working project which I imported and all working fine in eclispe but then when  I checkedout other branch which was missing .project, .classpath, etc eclispe config files then that project won't work even though iit was working previously for obvious reason. What fixed it was mvn eclipse:eclipse on command line. I know its deprecated but m2e doesnt help when your project is already imported in eclispe.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe some error has prevented Eclipse from finishing the project configuration. Try to force it again by doing this: **Right-click on the project** > **Maven** > **Update Project**. Wait for Eclipse to finish parsing your `pom.xml` and configuring the project again. Sometimes it takes some minutes while all dependencies are downloaded. You'll notice some background activity on Eclipse status-bar.

Besides that, before importing any Maven project, check its raw folder and get rid of `.classpath`, `.settings` and `.project` Eclipse files if they're already there. In case they were even versioned, ignore them on your version control system. The golden rule is: **never version Eclipse configurations to the rest of the team** so you can let Eclipse configure the new imported project from scratch on every workspace, since they can be slightly different.

Another great thing to do is to align Eclipse with your command line by adding your external Maven installation to it: **Window** > **Preferences** > **Maven** > **Instalations** > **Add..** > After adding it, deselect the embedded installation and select your instalattion as the default.

Comment: No change from update project. I updated the posting with a little more info.

Comment: @DavidM.Karr have a look at your `pom.xml` **build** section and see if there's any suspicious snippet that could be conflicting with your Eclipse environment.